# Phpmailer authentication failed but no credential changes

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHPMAILER to send confirmation emails etc. I started to get the following error 2 days ago (I thought it might just go away but seems to be an actual issue):

Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

I checked the credentials and they are ok. I am using office365 exchange login and tried to login and it works. It looks like I am on version 6.05 and the current version is 6.5 could that be the cause?

Here is what a snippet of the credentials look like:

```
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

function tep_htmlmail($to_name, $to_email_address, $email_subject, $email_text, $from_email_name, $from_email_address) {





// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.office365.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'email@mysite.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'MyPassword';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
//Server settings
//$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();

//Recipients
    $mail->setFrom($from_email_address, $from_email_name);
    $mail->addReplyTo($from_email_address, $from_email_name);
```

Comment: Add `$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;`, and see what additional information that might give.

Comment: this seems to be the error: 2022-07-13 14:32:13 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_disabled for more information. [

Comment: so I checked on that link regarding the error. I was/am trying to send with an account that is not "licensed" it is a general mailbox that does not have its own paid for license which I did not have a problem doing before but maybe now microsoft made a change?

Comment: Very likely. Gmail have done the same.

Comment: I still think it might be that, but I tried changing it to my personal account credentials and enabling the smtp authentication and its still not working. Maybe I am missing somehting

Comment: If you use your personal account you need to create an App Password in your Microsoft account and use that to authenticate from php. Your regular credentials won't work, it's another security feature. And the From address must be the address of your account, you cannot send on behalf of others (you can maybe put their address in the reply-to field if you need to)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up paying for an account for the general inbox, which just took a little bit of time to propagate I guess because it started to work.