Sending email with php
I want to send emails through my php webapp, I always did it through phpmailer (a php library installed with composer) and a outlook account. But they have changed the authentication type (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/error-535-57139-authentication-unsuccessful-basic/6a18c08d-6163-4a44-8e09-33bdecfb1d0f). But what I understand is that the phpmailer doesn't have the newest authentication type which is needed for services like outlook. Is there another library that does or can i modify the settings of phpmailer to allow the current authentication type. (also other email providers don't work anymore: i tried outlook and yahoo. gmail does support it but just until january 2025 and i want a long term solution).
Is there a workaround?
This is the code I tried:
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require("vendor/autoload.php");

function sendmail()
{
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    try {
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'email';
        $mail->Password = 'supersecurepassword';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    
        $mail->setFrom('email', 'name');
        $mail->addAddress('email');
        $mail->isHTML(true);
    
        $mail->Subject = 'Test Email';
        $mail->Body    = '<h1>Welcome to Our Service</h1><p>Enjoy your experience!</p>';
        
        $mail->send();
        echo "Message sent successfully!";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
}

This is the error when i run this code:
2024-12-02 21:27:41 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, basic authentication is disabled. [AM0PR02CA0198.eurprd02.prod.outlook.com 2024-12-02T21:27:41.476Z 08DD12F68033AE4D]
2024-12-02 21:27:41 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, basic authentication is disabled. [AM0PR02CA0198.eurprd02.prod.outlook.com 2024-12-02T21:27:41.476Z 08DD12F68033AE4D]
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2024-12-02 21:27:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2024-12-02 21:27:41 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
Message could not be sent. Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

It is just a side project so I don't want extra costs and i dont have microsoft 365 just a regular outlook account. Are there options for that or can I just forget sending emails in my side project?

Related:https://stackoverflow.com/q/73868867/14853083

Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72967686/phpmailer-authentication-failed-but-no-credential-changes

Uh, PHPMailer does support Microsoft's latest OAuth auth system, since it's "just" XOAUTH2, the same as many other providers. The problem is really that Microsoft's auth system is extremely difficult to use; setting up your account and getting the right keys and values is extraordinarily complicated and error-prone, and even outright broken in places, but none of that has anything to do with PHPMailer. More background discussion here

The trouble is that most major email providers are more or less removing authenticated SMTP altogether and moving to various proprietary message submission methods. Eg: MS wants your to use their Graph API to send email these days, which would require you to use a totally different library like the msgraph SDK.
Alternatively you can configure a special mail connector just for this one app to use SMTP again.
And then there's also the "don't touch MS at all and just use a 3rd party transactional mail provider" option.
Dead last option would be to beg you org to re-enable legacy SMTP auth, but MS will be permanently removing that as of September 2025.

So there is no way to send emails through SMTP in the long term, and then I would need to use the SDK microsoft provided and sending emails through that?

The "special mail connector" would work with SMTP, but you need to talk to your M365 admin about setting it up. But if this is for your app to send a boatload of "thanks for signing up/thanks for purchase/account updated" etc emails then I would strongly recommend a transactional email provider, as MS is likely to get on your case about outbound volume and/or reputation.

sendgrid provides a very good solution for smtp sending.  https://sendgrid.com
